# How to use the below expression in my SQL Query

Tags: sybase

I have this expression for sorting. I need to use this expression in my SQL code for the sorting purpose. Can anyone help me with this??

I tried case when stmt but it fails.

Expression:

```
if ([All Accounts].[ea_end_of_activity] is missing or 
[All Accounts].[ea_end_of_activity] is null)
then (
if   ([Japanese Accounts].[aco_ac_ea_id] is missing)
then ('1')
else ('0')
)
else ('2')
+
[All Accounts].[aco_acc_short_name]
```

CODE:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    First.aco_ac_ea_id,
    Sec.aco_acc_short_name,
    Sec.aco_acc_marketing,
    Sec.ea_spark_number,
    Sec.ea_end_of_activity
FROM
    (
    SELECT aco_ac_ea_id                                            
    FROM CD.dbo.MAC
    WHERE
    MAC.aco_locale = 'ja' AND
    MAC.aco_acc_marketing_status = 'VALIDATED'
    ) as First
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT
     aco_ac_ea_id,
     aco_acc_short_name,
     aco_acc_marketing,
     ea_spark_number,
    ea_end_of_activity
    FROM
    CD.dbo.MAC,
    CD.dbo.MEA
    WHERE
    MAC.aco_locale ='en-us' and
    MAC.aco_ac_ea_id = MEA.ea_id
    ) as Sec
ON First.aco_ac_ea_id=Sec.aco_ac_ea_id
```

Comment: Add the whole query you used. We have no idea where you used this expression. In the `ORDER BY` or in some other clause of the query?

Comment: in ORDER BY Clause. This is cognos expression. I need to use it my SQL code. So i guess it will go like 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN { } ..something like this.

Comment: Yes, you can use a case expression (it is not a statement) in order by, eg. `ORDER BY CASE ... END` in Sybase, as far as I know. What you have shown is not even valid SQL (what is this `is missing`?)

Comment: I have shared my code as well. Now i need to sort the o/p of my above code based on the expression.
 The first is "Japan Accounts" and sec is "All accounts".

Comment: We still don't know what means `is missing`. Can you explain that? Show us how do you tried use `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question but the `DISTINCT` seems useless for this query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No idea what the `is missing` is supposed to mean (is it the same as `is null`?). If yes, the `CASE` expression and the `ORDER BY` can be written like this:

```
ORDER BY
  CASE 
    WHEN Sec.ea_end_of_activity IS NOT NULL
      THEN 2
    WHEN First.aco_ac_ea_id IS NULL 
      THEN 1
    ELSE 0 
  END,
  Sec.aco_acc_short_name ;
```

The `First.` and `Sec.` can be omitted (at least in other DBMS, not 100% sure about Sybase), since they are in the `SELECT` list.